# How to Fix Error in Multiple Importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am creating a table to display data from a combination of several Spreadsheet files by using Multiple Importrange.

```
= QUERY ({Importrange (G3, "Sheet1! A2: D"); Importrange (G4, "Sheet1! A2: D"); Importrange (G5, "Sheet1! A2: D")}, "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 Where Col3 Is Not Null And Col4 Is Not Null ")
```

The formula above has gone well.
[image: Works]
My file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eL06DChMSkLuOOj9YNK6KUsVUIqbjcYlKS8pZHLmt_0/edit#gid=0

I insert some Spreadsheet files into the "List Link" table.
The link in the table has 3 links.

What I want to ask is how do I overcome the multiple importrange error when the link in the table does not yet exist?

The formula that I have changed is like this:

```
= IFERROR (QUERY ({Importrange (G3, "Sheet1! A2: D"); Importrange (G4, "Sheet1! A2: D"); Importrange (G5, "Sheet1! A2: D"); Importrange (G6, " Sheet1! A2: D "); Importrange (G7," Sheet1! A2: D ")}," Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 Where Col3 Is Not Null And Col4 Is Not Null "))
```

The result is empty.
[image: Empty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each individual `IMPORTRANGE` call in `IFERROR` with a null array as the default length of a filled row if there is an error, like this:

`=QUERY({
IFERROR(Importrange(G3,"Sheet1!A2:D"),{"","","",""});
IFERROR(Importrange(G4,"Sheet1!A2:D"),{"","","",""});
IFERROR(Importrange(G5,"Sheet1!A2:D"),{"","","",""});
IFERROR(Importrange(G6,"Sheet1!A2:D"),{"","","",""});
IFERROR(Importrange(G7,"Sheet1!A2:D"),{"","","",""})
},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 Where Col3 Is Not Null And Col4 Is Not Null")`

Comment: It's work. Thanks sir.

Comment: Happy to help you resolve your issue.